# Is there a way i can fix this login code multiple queries in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, ddos

**I'm trying to create a login route where it can accept username or email  below one problem is when i make a normal query when either email or username is available the other is undefined and gives this error My regex is designed to escape DDos proof and it also escapes caseSensitive it returns undefined for either of the field if one is empty

````
  if (!req.body) {
    res.send("Empty body");
  }
  emailb = req.body.email;
  usernameb = req.body.username;
  if (emailb || usernameb === undefined) {
    let email = req.body.email;
    let regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(email), "gi");
    let username = req.body.username;
    let regexuser = new RegExp(escapeRegex(username), "gi");
    User.find()
      .or([{ email: regex }, { username: regexuser }])
      .then((user) => {
          return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        })
          .then((err, valid) => {
            if (err) {
              res.send("incorrect password");
            }
            if (valid && !user.verified) {
              res.status(401).send("PLEASE VERIFY EITHER EMAIL OR PHONE!");
            }
            return user;
          })
          .then((user) => {
            const token = jwt.sign(
              {
                email: user.email,
                phone: user.phone,
                userid: user._id,
              },
              process.env.SECRET_JWT
            );
            res.status(200).json({ token: token, userid: user._id });
          }).catch(error => { res.send(error) })

  }```
```function escapeRegex(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the promises usage wrong use of promises i used there was an interesting error that occured while using regex for both username or mail i saw that it was easier to use one field as username and email i was using 2 fields for username and email that is why whenever on field would be empty it would return undefined with top of regex it made another confusing error cannot replace because i used a ddos proof attack model regex.decided to use 1 field for username and email input and structured my code well and thats it

```
  if (!req.body) {
    res.send("Empty body");
  }
  loginValidation(req.body);
  let username = req.body.username;
  let regexuser = new RegExp(escapeRegex(username), "gi");

  // User.findOne({
  //   $or:[
  //     {'condition_1':param}, {'condition_2':param}
  //   ]},
  User.findOne({
    $or: [{ username: regexuser }, { email: regexuser }, { phone: req.body.phone }],
  })
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          error: `Couldn't find User ${req.body.username}`,
        });
      } else {
        if (!user.verified) {
          return res.status(200).json({
            token: "",
            error: `Please verify Account  ${req.body.email} Or PhoneNumber ${user.phone}`,
          });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
        const token = jwt.sign(
          {
            email: user.email,
            phone: user.phone,
            userid: user._id,
          },
          process.env.SECRET_JWT
        );
        res.status(200).json({ token: token, userid: user._id });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error);
    });
```